# Sharing dynamic links from React Native app using Firebase or Branch.io results in redirection to App Store on iOS real devices even if app installed

Tags: react-native, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase, mobile-development

I have implemented Firebase Dynamic Links in my React Native app, following all the configuration steps provided in the official Firebase documentation. The dynamic links are functioning correctly on the Android simulator, Android real device, and iOS simulator. However, when testing on an iOS real device, the dynamic links consistently redirect to the App Store, even when the app is already installed on the device.

To further investigate the issue, I also tried using the Branch.io SDK as an alternative solution. I set up the Branch.io SDK in my React Native app, following the necessary configurations and integration steps. However, I encountered the same problem as mentioned above - dynamic links on iOS real devices always redirect to the App Store, regardless of the app being installed on the device.

I have tested this issue on three iOS devices running OS versions 16.1.1 and 16.0.3. Despite researching the problem, double-checking my configurations, and attempting to use the Branch.io SDK as an alternative, the dynamic links continue to redirect to the App Store on real iOS devices.

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue and ensuring that dynamic links on iOS real devices properly redirect to the app when it is already installed, regardless of whether Firebase Dynamic Links or Branch.io SDK is used.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Set up Firebase Dynamic Links or Branch.io SDK in a React Native app following the respective documentation.
2. Generate a dynamic link using the chosen solution (Firebase or Branch.io).
3. Share the dynamic link with an iOS device having the app installed.
4. Click on the dynamic link from a messaging app or any other platform.
5. Observe that instead of opening the app, the iOS device redirects to the App Store.

**Expected Behavior:**
When the app is already installed on an iOS device, clicking on a dynamic link should open the app directly, without redirecting to the App Store.

**Project Configurations**
**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^16.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^16.4.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.3"
  }
```

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // some default code...
  [FIRApp configure];
  // rest of the code...
  
  return YES;
}
```